# Copy_Paste_Visible_Cells_Only

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to Copy the Filtered data and pasting the data on filtered cell but my code is not working.

I have data in Range `Sheet2.Range("O2:O10000")` and i filtered this range to `Sheet2.Range("O173:O2400")`.

I want to copy the data from filtered cells `Sheet2.Range("O173:O2400")` then paste this data to visible cells on same `Sheet2.Range("N173:N2400")`

Please note there are multiple hidden rows in this range.

Any help will be appreciated

```
Sub Copy_Paste__Visible_Cells_Only()

    Sheet2.Range("O173:O2400").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

    Sheet2.Range("N173:N2400").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, pasting won't work. As far as I know, you can't change the paste behaviour to only paste to visible cells.

When you select visible cells only, you get a collection of `areas` (you can think of them as a discontinuous set of `ranges`). Given you're just trying to move your visible data to the left, you can do it by looping through the `areas` and assigning their values to the same area in the previous column. Something like this:

```
Public Sub CopyVisible()
    Dim a As Range
    For Each a In Sheet1.Range("O4:O17").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
        a.Offset(0, -1).Value = a.Value
    Next
End Sub
```

The `.Offset(0,-1)` is signalling that you wish the values to be moved one column to the left

You can see from this example, when I filter on "a" in column O and run the macro, only the "a" values are moved to column N.

[image]

Comment: No its not working it is pasting the data on hided rows

Comment: Hi @ShRa. I've updated the answer now that your requirements are more clear

Answer (score 0):

I would use a generic sub `copyVisibleCellsToOtherColumn` to which you pass the source-range and the target-start range.
Advantage you can re-use it for different scenarios.

```
Sub test_CopyVisibleCells()
Dim rgSource As Range
Set rgSource = sheet2.Range("O173:O2400")

Dim rgTarget As Range
Set rgTarget = sheet2.Range("N173:02400")

copyVisibleCells rgSource, rgTarget
End Sub

'this ist the generic sub
Public Sub copyVisibleCellsToOtherColumn(rgSource As Range, rgTarget As Range)
Dim c As Range, a As Range
For Each a In rgSource.Areas
    'this will return the visible cells within rgsource
    For Each c In a.Cells
        rgTarget.Rows(c.Row).Value = c.Value
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried but after some rows it is pasting the data into hidden rows.

Comment: That definitly will happen if you paste on the same sheet - no way to change that. What is your basic requirement? Maybe you should use a completely different solution.

Comment: No i also tried on different sheet the result was same and its sequence was also not arranged. all the data was shuffled. I looked around and tried to find solution but all in vain

Comment: Then:  Please edit your _question_ and explain what exactly is your requirement?

Comment: updated the answer to your new requirment

Comment: This is equivalent to my answer, except that you additionally loop through the cells in the area. I don't think `rngTarget.Rows(c.Row)` does what you want if the source and target are not on the same rows? If that's the case, it kinda defeats the object of being specific about the target range, when it's always going to be some integer offset.

Comment: I think our answers overlapped. In the end the requirements are not clear enough to know what is the correct solution ...

Answer (score 0):

I found code from somewhere which able to copy visible cells and paste into visible cells. For easy usage, I manually assign a shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to call the macro.

```
Public Sub Copy_Range_Paste_Into_Visible_Cells()
'Sub Copy_Range_Paste_Into_Visible_Cells()

Dim rngSource As Range, rngDestination As Range, cell As Range, cc As Long, i As Long

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set rngSource = Application.InputBox("Select the filtered range to copy. ", "Select Filtered Cells", Type:=8)
If rngSource Is Nothing Then Application.DisplayAlerts = True: Exit Sub   'User canceled

Set rngDestination = Application.InputBox("Select the destination cell to paste to. ", "Select Paste Destination", Type:=8)
If rngDestination Is Nothing Then Application.DisplayAlerts = True: Exit Sub  'User canceled

On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

cc = rngSource.Columns.Count

For Each cell In rngSource.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Do Until Not rngDestination(1).Offset(i).EntireRow.Hidden
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    rngDestination(1).Offset(i).Resize(1, cc).Value = cell.Resize(1, cc).Value
    i = i + 1
Next

End Sub
```